# How to convert seconds to format HH:mm:ss in Kusto

Tags: azure, logging, type-conversion, azure-data-explorer, kql

I would like to know the best way to transform a duration in seconds in something more user friendly like HH:MM:SS.

I have found a solution, but I don't think it's the best one:

I use a random datetime `make_datetime(2017,1,1)`, I add the amount of seconds with `datetime_add` and then I format the result to get "HH:mm:ss"

```
AzureDiagnostics 

| project  

Duration = format_datetime(
                   datetime_add('second',
                                toint(Output_copyDuration_d),
                                make_datetime(2017,1,1)
                                ),
                   "HH:mm:ss")
```

where Output_copyDuration_d is the duration stored in seconds

My results are correct

if Output_copyDuration_d = 234 then I get Duration =  00:03:54

Answer (score 11, accepted):

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/datetime-timespan-arithmetic

for instance:

```
print seconds_as_timespan = 1234 * 1s
```

which returns `00:20:34`